# Use UI or Template for helpers

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I'm just learning Meteor and I've defined a few helpers that I use in my templates.

I've noticed that I can do this in two different ways, but which solution is considered best practice? And why?

Solution 1

```
UI.registerHelper('firstChar', function (name) {
  return name.charAt(0);
});
```

Solution 2

```
Template.registerHelper('firstChar', function (name) {
  return name.charAt(0);
});
```

Comment: Solution 1 is better practice, here's why. When components land (after the new template engine), templates will be thought of as simple component classes, which can have subclasses and instances participating in a prototype chain, which may help explain why they are now objects rather than functions. If not returning an object itself; **UI.registerHelper** is best to return what you need... More information is here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#new-template-compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stick to solution 2, because this is what is currently documented : https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper

The first solution use the previous namespace to define Spacebars helpers (`UI`), and has been deprecated for months.